# Google Maps not loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gmaps.js

I am using this JavaScript code to my sample site and I am including a Google Map there, however the Map does not load when the page loads.

UPDATE - Also, I've noticed if I leave the web page open for a long period of time some parts of the google map get loaded.

Is this an error with the code I've written or some form of a lag.

Any kind of help is appreciated

HTML

```
<head>
    <script src="js/gmaps.js"/></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <section id="properties" class="container">
            <article id="prop1">
                <div id="tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#map">Location</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="map"></div>
                    </div>
            </article>
            </body>
            </html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>    
       GMaps({//maps UI
    el: '#map', 
    lat: 52.97,
    lng: -2.44
  });
            </script>
```

Comment: please show us more of your html code + java script code which is relevant e.g. your java script references p.s. omit your api key

Comment: any warning in console?

Comment: There isn't any warning in the console, when the page loads you can see that there is a Google map here because of the google map tools but the map itself is not visible at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `el` to `div` like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    GMaps({//maps UI
        div: '#map', 
        lat: 52.97,
        lng: -2.44
    });
});
```

Just check the documentation : https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/basic.html

Comment: Very sorry about the previous code it just simply had a JavaScript code. I hope this updated version will help in solving the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you check on the ressource tab or network tab of chrome if your js is downloaded and loaded please ?

Comment: @IsiraK I'v just edited my post, please check it out

Comment: the js is from a local file so I just have to check in the loaded section right? And yes, it is loaded along with the rest. 
Is there some issue with the loading of Google maps?

Comment: @IsiraK yes, check if the script is downloaded and check my post with 'div' and 'el'